# How do I test the speed of file transfers on my LAN?

Tags: wireless-networking, speed, lan, data-transfer

I have a Macbook Pro (wirelessly connected to the Internet) and a G5 tower (connected via ethernet). The MBP wirelessly backs up to an external drive on the G5 tower. I would like to know how fast the data transfer is between the MBP and the G5. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to copy a large file, eg. movie, between Macbook Pro and G5, and then measure the speed, should be in range of 5 to 10 megabyte per second, if your router supports 802.11n standard.

Comment: How do I measure the speed?

Comment: The simplest way is to make notion of how many seconds it took to copy the a file, check the file size and then divide the number of megabytes by number of seconds.